# Media (images, videos, etc.) not showing on Category page

Tags: categories, archives, media, videos

I'm having a problem where media isn't showing up on the Category page. (It's actually the exact same problem that's described in [this WordPress.org forum post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/embedded-images-and-videos-not-showing-in-archive-and-category-view), but it's so out of date that the solution doesn't appear to apply anymore.)

I've checked `category.php` and I'm guessing it's something to do with `<?php get_template_part( 'entry' ); ?>` ? I'm using the [Blankslate theme](http://wordpress.org/themes/blankslate).

Contents of `entry.php`:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<header>
<?php if ( is_singular() ) { echo '<h1 class="entry-title">'; } else { echo '<h2 class="entry-title">'; } ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a><?php if ( is_singular() ) { echo '</h1>'; } else { echo '</h2>'; } ?> <?php edit_post_link(); ?>
<?php if ( !is_search() ) get_template_part( 'entry', 'meta' ); ?>
</header>
<?php get_template_part( 'entry', ( is_archive() || is_search() ? 'summary' : 'content' ) ); ?>
<?php if ( !is_search() ) get_template_part( 'entry-footer' ); ?>
</article>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is there a file called entry.php? if you're working on the default theme then 'entry' needs to become 'content','entry'

Comment: @GarethGillman Yes, thanks. I just added the contents of entry.php to the question. Where should 'entry' be changed to 'content', 'entry'?

Comment: get_template_part('entry') looks for a file called entry.php (which is the file it's being called from), you need to add a new file e.g. content.php and then change get_template_part('entry') to get_template_part('content') and then add the WordPress loop to content.php

Comment: Oops! I pasted category.php instead of entry.php by mistake!

Answer (score 1):

Your entry.php template is completely wrong. This should be your loop so to speak. Yet this is more like a page template, that also calls for entry.php. This template should include the call to your `the_content()`, media files, comments if applicable, and the title, also all other things you might want to include in your loop

You should have something like this in your entry.php. This is from content.php from the twentyfourteen theme

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <?php twentyfourteen_post_thumbnail(); ?>

    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php if ( in_array( 'category', get_object_taxonomies( get_post_type() ) ) && twentyfourteen_categorized_blog() ) : ?>
        <div class="entry-meta">
            <span class="cat-links"><?php echo get_the_category_list( _x( ', ', 'Used between list items, there is a space after the comma.', 'twentyfourteen' ) ); ?></span>
        </div>
        <?php
            endif;

            if ( is_single() ) :
                the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' );
            else :
                the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h1>' );
            endif;
        ?>

        <div class="entry-meta">
            <?php
                if ( 'post' == get_post_type() )
                    twentyfourteen_posted_on();

                if ( ! post_password_required() && ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) ) :
            ?>
            <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'twentyfourteen' ), __( '1 Comment', 'twentyfourteen' ), __( '% Comments', 'twentyfourteen' ) ); ?></span>
            <?php
                endif;

                edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentyfourteen' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' );
            ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <?php if ( is_search() ) : ?>
    <div class="entry-summary">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <?php else : ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php
            the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyfourteen' ) );
            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before'      => '<div class="page-links"><span class="page-links-title">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyfourteen' ) . '</span>',
                'after'       => '</div>',
                'link_before' => '<span>',
                'link_after'  => '</span>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php the_tags( '<footer class="entry-meta"><span class="tag-links">', '', '</span></footer>' ); ?>
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

It is a good idea to have a look at the default themes shipped with wordpress.

Comment: It's from Blankslate :-/ http://wordpress.org/themes/blankslate Weird that you think they've messed it up?

Comment: Oops! I pasted category.php instead of entry.php by mistake!

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I originally pasted the wrong file contents into the question. I figured out my own answer.

I changed `entry.php` from this:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<header>
<?php if ( is_singular() ) { echo '<h1 class="entry-title">'; } else { echo '<h2 class="entry-title">'; } ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a><?php if ( is_singular() ) { echo '</h1>'; } else { echo '</h2>'; } ?> <?php edit_post_link(); ?>
<?php if ( !is_search() ) get_template_part( 'entry', 'meta' ); ?>
</header>
<?php get_template_part( 'entry', ( is_archive() || is_search() ? 'summary' : 'content' ) ); ?>
<?php if ( !is_search() ) get_template_part( 'entry-footer' ); ?>
</article>
```

To this:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<header>
<?php if ( is_singular() ) { echo '<h1 class="entry-title">'; } else { echo '<h2 class="entry-title">'; } ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a><?php if ( is_singular() ) { echo '</h1>'; } else { echo '</h2>'; } ?> <?php edit_post_link(); ?>
<?php if ( !is_search() ) get_template_part( 'entry', 'meta' ); ?>
</header>
<?php get_template_part( 'entry', 'content'); ?> <!-- EDIT HERE -->
<?php if ( !is_search() ) get_template_part( 'entry-footer' ); ?>
</article>
```

It was checking to see if it was an archive page (e.g. category) and only showing the 'summary' if it was. I removed that so it always showed the 'content'.

Fixed!

Comment: Was just updating my answer with the very same info, lol. Glad you sorted it out. Enjoy